# I wish to attend my stepfather's funeral

Tags: visas

I'm a Kenyan citizen. I have lost my stepfather, who is a British citizen. Is it possible for me to get an emergency visa to come and attend his funeral? Thank you.

Comment: My condolences on your loss.